# Drawing Neural Network diagram for academic papers

Tags: neural-network, software-recommendation

Is there any tool that one can use to draw neural network architecture diagram for research papers?
Example diagram: 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are few online tools available that give you ability to draw "canned" CNN  diagrams like [NN-SVG](http://alexlenail.me/NN-SVG/LeNet.html)
EXAMPLE : [image]

Another popular choice seems to be [InkScape](https://inkscape.org)

There is always PowerPoint

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, most researchers use general drawing tools to visualizes neural network architectures. Although there are some libraries to do it automatically. However, the visualizations in your paper are quite important to get your ideas across and using custom hand-made visuals allows you to visually explain your work in the most appropriate way (not being limited to the design choices of an automated drawing library).

Therefore, I suggest to just use a general drawing tool of your choice. Also, MS PowerPoint or Google Slides can be quite convenient to draw shapes as in above picture.