# Looking for Code to Generate CNN Architecture Visualization from Model Summary

Tags: cnn, automatic-summarization

I am looking for code that generates a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) architecture image from a model summary (similar to the attached image).
Thanks for the help!
[image: similar to the attached image]

Comment: This has already been asked multiple times on this site, see [How to draw Deep learning network architecture diagrams?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/14899/how-to-draw-deep-learning-network-architecture-diagrams), [How to draw neural network diagrams with this particular style?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/63195/14675), [How do you visualize neural network architectures?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/12851/14675), [Drawing Neural Network diagram for academic papers](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/66343/14675), and more.

Comment: Thank you for your response!